# Error before start of result set. Multiple outputs if the same button is clicked

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

How can I stop resultset from displaying the same result when I click the button show?

This is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6A8P.jpg) of the table:

[image]

It's annoying that it outputs the same. Do I need to disable the button after a result set? Here is my code:

```
    ps = c.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM sample.table WHERE plate = '"+plate_number.getText()+"'");
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
    String plate = rs.getString(1);
    String owner = rs.getString(2);
    String number = rs.getString(3);
    String driver = rs.getString(4);
    String route = rs.getString(5);
    Object[] content = {plate, owner, number, driver, route};

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    model.addRow(content);
```

Comment: where did you put this code ? inside a loop??

Comment: Assuming its the issue, do you clear the table model? `model.setRowCount(0);` before the query might help.

Comment: @FastSnail I didn't used any loops.

Comment: @Matthew I'll try it later. Thank you for the reply.